# clientcert can only be configured for "hostssl" rows

Tags: postgresql, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

i am trying to add `clientcert=1` in `pg_hba.conf` 
can anyone tell me where to add this ? I'm trying to add postgres as a db in fabric-ca with `sslmode=verify-ca`

my `pg_hba.conf` looks like this

```
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust clientcert=1
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all md5
```

Comment: Like the error says, you want "hostssl" for the "clientcert" setting. Doesn't make sense for non-ssl connections, does it? See the extensive manuals for details.

Comment: @RichardHuxton thanks for answering, but i tried removing clientcert=1 from there and tried adding hostssl all all all md5 clientcert=1 in the end of my file and it resolved.